# Detect and/or prevent duplicate select values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `<form>` with multiple pairs of `<select>'s` that all use the same set of `<option>'s`, but I want to ensure the user doesn't select the same set of options across any of the pairs. The combined values of the selects in any given pair should not be used elsewhere. Pairs can be added or removed dynamically, they just can't submit the form if any 2 pairs are the same. A1 & B1 is a pair, A2 & B2 is a pair, and so on. As for when to check, I think on submit would be best.

I was taking this approach before I realized it was a terrible way of doing it...

```
var selects = [];

$('#col1 select').each(function(){
    var index = $(this).parent().attr('id').substring(1);
    var value1 = this.value;
    var value2 = $('#b' + index + ' select').val();
    var entry = value1+value2;
    selects.push(entry);
});

// loop through selects looking for duplicates
```

Here is the HTML in question...

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; }
  
#column1,
#column2 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  width: 49%;}
  
 #column1 div,
 #column2 div {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<div id="column1">
  <div id="a1">
    <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="a2">
    <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="a3">
    <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="column2">
  <div id="b1">
    <select>
      <option value="alpha">alpha</option>
      <option value="bravo">bravo</option>
      <option value="charlie">charlie</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="b2">
    <select>
      <option value="alpha">alpha</option>
      <option value="bravo">bravo</option>
      <option value="charlie">charlie</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="b3">
    <select>
      <option value="alpha">alpha</option>
      <option value="bravo">bravo</option>
      <option value="charlie">charlie</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not use radio buttons and style them as a list? A better solution if Javascript and CSS are disabled (unlikely but it could be possible).

Comment: Just so i'm clear; you want it so that if `a1 -> value1` is selected, then `a2 -> value1` cannot be selected, only `a2 -> value2` is selectable. Similarly for the b's. Is that correct?

Comment: @Waxi Please use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) instead of jsfiddle.

Comment: Is the checking to occur when the form is submitted or every time an option is changed?

Comment: @j08691 It doesn't matter when the check happens, whatever is easier, probably on submit?

Comment: @Sasang Every 'row' has 2 selects, I don't want the same combination of selects being used in another row, I've added a snippet to show how it looks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **classes** to represent sets. You can then more generally iterate through the sets, as columns and rows, instead of by ids.

```js
function getPairs(){
 var pairs = [];
 var cols = $('.col');
 var rows = $('.row',cols[0]);
 //iterate through row i of each column
 for(var r = 0; r < rows.length; r++){
     var val = "";
     for(var c = 0; c < cols.length; c++){
         val += $('.row select',cols[c])[r].value;
     }
     pairs.push(val);
 }
 return pairs;
}

$("#btn").click(function(){
  console.log(getPairs()); 
});
//console.log(getPairs());
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box;}

/* hack to fix console overlapping content of snippet result*/
div.as-console-wrapper { position: initial; }

.col {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
  vertical-align:top;}
  
.row {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;}
  
select,
option {
  display: block;
  width: 100%:}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="column1" class="col">
  <div id="a1" class="row">
    <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="a2" class="row">
    <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="a3" class="row">
    <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="column2" class="col">
  <div id="b1" class="row">
    <select>
      <option value="alpha">alpha</option>
      <option value="bravo">bravo</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="b2" class="row">
    <select>
      <option value="alpha">alpha</option>
      <option value="bravo">bravo</option>
    </select>
  </div>
   <div id="b3" class="row">
    <select>
      <option value="alpha">alpha</option>
      <option value="bravo">bravo</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<p><input type="button" id="btn" value="Log Result" /></p>
```

Comment: The console is clearly in the way here. There is a button it hides =/ I am going to remove the initial console.log() call. Keep in mind the console will overwrite it after click, this is bad design, but is a feature of Stack Overflow and not of this answer itself.

Comment: If you were inclined to screen this for duplicates, in the getPairs function you could simply expand `pairs.push(val);` to be `if(pairs.indexOf(val) > -1)` to determine duplication.

Comment: Yeah your approach is a better than trying to manage ID's and I can modify it as needed now that I see how you've done it, thank you.